# Question about the math notation when studying Euler equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, differentiation, vector-fields, flow, navier-stokes

I am trying to work out the Euler equation. However, I find some difficulties of the following step. Am I doing the right things and how could I get into the last step? Thanks a lot.
$$ \nabla (\vec{v} \otimes \vec{v}) $$
$$ = \nabla \left[ \begin{pmatrix} u \\ v \\ w \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} u & v & w \end{pmatrix} \right]$$
$$ =  \nabla \begin{pmatrix}
u^2 & uv & uw\\ uv & v^2 & vw \\ uw & vw & w^2 
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$ = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
u^2 & uv & uw\\ uv & v^2 & vw \\ uw & vw & w^2 
\end{pmatrix}$$
The result I am looking for should be look like:
$$ = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \begin{pmatrix} u^2 \\ uv \\uw \end{pmatrix} + 
 \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \begin{pmatrix} uv \\ v^2 \\vw \end{pmatrix} +
   \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \begin{pmatrix} uw \\ vw \\w^2 \end{pmatrix}$$
While when I keep working, I get the following row vector insteat.
$$  \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} u^2 + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} (uv) + \frac{\partial}{\partial z} (uw) & \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (uv) + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} v^2 + \frac{\partial}{\partial z} (vw) & \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (uw) + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} (vw) + \frac{\partial}{\partial z} w^2 \end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: Hint: One is the transpose of the other.

Comment: @JAlex yes I also realize that, how could I convert it into what I expect ?

Comment: The problem isn't with you, but with the vector calculus notation which is dimensional inconsistent. Some people directly jump into $\rm grad$, $\rm div$ and $\rm curl$ notation instead of the jack of all trades $\nabla$ which changes form depending on the context.

Comment: That would be a column vector.

Comment: @JAlex Could you explain more on this? or shell I use the notation that shown in Wikipedia? $\nabla \cdot T = \frac{\partial T_{ji}}{\partial x_j}e_i$

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know enough about the Euler equation to help much. I took vector calculus i college and although comprehensive it wasn't as intuitive as I hoped for.

Answer (score 2):

One thing—it seems like the object you're attempting to calculate is $\nabla \cdot \left(\vec{v} \otimes \vec{v}\right)$, not $\nabla \left(\vec{v} \otimes \vec{v}\right)$.

Also, the object you're calculating is just the transpose of the other; you'll notice it more clearly if you bring the differentiation operator into the parentheses and add up. When it comes to the question of why you get a row vector vs. a column vector, it's because the "mnemonic" of defining $\nabla = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\end{pmatrix}$ with a row vector isn't technically correct and an abuse of notation, which leads to some dimensional inconsistencies if applied directly. A more accurate approach, which is coordinate-independent but maybe a bit more confusing, is this definition of $\nabla$:

$$\nabla = \lim_{V \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{V}\int\int_S \vec{n}[...] dS$$

where the stuff inside the brackets can also be an operation (like $\cdot f$ for $\nabla \cdot f$).

Regardless, when the result is intrepreted as a vector (independent of row/column "orientation"), your result is correct.

Comment: Thanks, how should I define $\nobla$ here? I still can't figure out how can I get that result. What is the standard procedure to handle such kinds of notation instead of write it out as vectors?

Comment: I added a line on how to define $\nabla$ above.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. It is a notation problem.

It can be easily solved when using index notation, which I hate, but it is moore useful.

Acoording to index notation, you should be calculating:

$$ p_i= \sum_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} v_i v_j  $$

And this would be more like

$$(\vec{v}\otimes \vec{v})\cdot \vec{\nabla}$$

But this notation is obviously not good.

In sum, use index notation instead.